# Why my width-100% not working before 900px

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, responsive

When I am working on responsive then width 100% is not working, when I shrink my website. This problem is in my main section which is available after header section

my [github repo](https://github.com/aryan0k9/Test/tree/main/aevytv)

This is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bitter:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div>
                <img src="images/yuewr.png" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Structure</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Impact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><button>ENROLL NOW <img src="images/arrow-right-up.svg"/> </button></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="first_section">
            <div class="first_section_ka_image_div">
                <img src="images/Frame-1.webp" alt="" srcset="" class="rotate">
            </div>
            <div class="first_section_ka_upper_div">
                <h5>GO FROM <span class="text_gradient_color">ZERO TO PRO</span> IN JUST 3 MONTHS</h5>
                <h1>THE BEST PLACEMENT FRIENDLY VIDEO EDITING COHORT MONEY CAN BUY.</h1>
                <div><button>WATCH FREE WEBINAR <img src="images/arrow-right-up.svg"/></button></div>
                <p class="text_gradient_color_white">*Applications for cohort-3 are open</p>
            </div>
            <div class="first_section-ka_opacity_div"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="second_section">
            <div class="second_section_ka_upper_opacity_div"></div>
            <div class="second_section_ka_middel_div">
                <h5><span class="text_gradient_color">SEE WHO’S HIRING VIDEO EDITORS</span></h5>
                <h1 class="font_w_s_c_t">OK, BUT WHERE’S THE DEMAND?</h1>
                <div class="second_section_ka_middel_div_ka_img_section">
                    <img src="images/Vector-4.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="images/Group-7.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="images/Group-8.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="images/Vector-2.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="images/Vector-3.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="images/Fill-1.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="images/Group-2.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="images/Group-1.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="images/Group-3.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="images/Vector-1.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="images/gngm.png" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="images/Layer-6.png" alt="" srcset="">
                    <img src="images/Layer-5.png" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="second_section_ka_lower_opacity_div">
                
            </div>
            <p class="text_gradient_color_white">& almost all the top companies around the globe are looking for visual storytellers</p>
        </div>
        <div class="third_section">
            <div class="third_section_ka_first_div">
                <p><span class="text_gradient_color">ALL YOUR FAVES NEED A VIDEO EDITOR</span></p>
                <h1 class="font_w_s_c_t">WANT TO WORK WITH TOP CREATORS?</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="third_section_ka_second_div">
                <div class="third_section_ka_second_div_ka_img">
                    <div>
                        <img src="images/sharan.jpeg" alt="" srcset="">
                        <h4>Finance with Sharan</h4>
                        <h6>1.5M<br>
                            FOLLOWERS</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="images/trja.png" alt="" srcset="">
                        <h4>Mo Vlogs</h4>
                        <h6>11.2M<br>
                            FOLLOWERS</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="images/techburner.jpeg" alt="" srcset="">
                        <h4>Tech Burner</h4>
                        <h6>10M<br>
                            FOLLOWERS</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="images/shashank.jpeg" alt="" srcset="">
                        <h4>Shashank Udupa</h4>
                        <h6>162K<br>
                            FOLLOWERS</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="images/nas.jpeg" alt="" srcset="">
                        <h4>Nas Daily</h4>
                        <h6>10.7M<br>
                            FOLLOWERS</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="images/ab.jpeg" alt="" srcset="">
                        <h4>Abhi and Niyu</h4>
                        <h6>3.6M<br>
                            FOLLOWERS</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="third_section_ka_second_div_ka_p">
                    <p><em><span class="text_gradient_color_white"> Students from the past cohort are already working with some of these creators and many more creators are hiring from the next cohort.</em>
                    </span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="forth_section">
            <div class="forth_section_first_div">
                <h5><span class="text_gradient_color">CHANGING LIVES ONE VIDEO AT A TIME</span></h5>
                <h1 class="font_w_s_c_t">THE IMPACT WE'VE CREATED</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="forth_section_second_div">
                <div class="forth_section_second_div_ka_first_div">
                    <h5>A 3.2 Cr Impact on GDI</h5>
                    <p>We are creating a huge impact on India’s GDI - Gross domestic income. Students from Cohort-1 are earning a total sum of 3.2 Crore in salaries annually.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="forth_section_second_div_ka_second_div">
                    <h5>Massive 3000% ROI</h5>
                    <p>Cohort has almost 30x Return on Investment. Students have been placed with CTCs up to 10L Per annum with an average salary of 50,000 Per month.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="forth_section_second_div_ka_third_div">
                    <h5>High Placement Rates</h5>
                    <p>71% students who opted for placements from Cohort-1 got jobs with some of the biggest Indian creators. For Cohort-2 the expected placement rate is 86%</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fifth_section">
            <div class="fifth_section_first_div">
                <h5><span class="text_gradient_color">STUDENT TRANSFORMATION STORY</span></h5>
                <h1 class="font_w_s_c_t">HERE'S WHAT OUR STUDENTS HAVE TO SAY</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="fifth_section_second_div">
                <div>
                    <video src="video/1.mp4" controls></video>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <video src="video/2.mp4" controls></video>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <video src="video/3.mp4" controls></video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sixth_section">
            <div class="sixth_section_first_div">
                <h5><span class="text_gradient_color">STUDENT TESTIMONIALS</span></h5>
                <h1 class="font_w_s_c_t">READ SOME MORE STORIES</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sixth_section_second_div">
                <div class="sixth_section_second_div_ka_first_content">
                    <div>
                        <h5>Sumanyu Sood - Cohort 1</h5>
                        <p>Hello, Ocus Before I joined the cohort, I was into UX/UI design. Many of my friends were getting good gigs doing video editing. So, I always used to wonder how I can also get some good gigs. I had some experience with video editing before, but joining the cohort actually made me to sit down and devote time to the video editing. Ask any member of the cohort, The two classes that Martin took for sound design were the best. All three mentors were really helpful, from taking lectures to clearing up doubts in zoom chats. The remedial classes were organized for the beginners to cope up with the softwares, really appreciate that. By the end of the cohort, I'm capable enough to edit different types of videos and I feel I'm applying lot of stuff I learned while designing into video editing I received several placement offers, and Ocus assisted me in sorting out all my queries regarding the placements with a quick personal call. The networks I was able to create through the community are also absolutely priceless, and I'm so happy that Aevy and the team organized this cohort to inspire this community to learn together and form wonderful relationships. I just want to thank you Ocus, Martin and Varun and everyone from the aevy team to make this cohort possible.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h5>Dileep Reddy - Cohort 2</h5>
                        <p>I had the privilege of joining the Cohort and I can say with certainty that it has been a game-changer for me. The network I've gained access to, which includes India's top editors, content creators, and freelancers, has been invaluable. My life took a turn for the better when I was offered an internship at Aevy, made possible through the mentorship of great leaders like Varun Mayya, Kuntur Sir papa ocus, and Martin. Their guidance continues to shape my present and future. This investment has been life-changing and I highly recommend it to anyone looking to take their career to the next level.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h5>Tushar Agarwal - Cohort 1</h5>
                        <p>Hey Shirsh! I just wanted to tell you that I got my first stipend as a "video editor" credited today and I really want to thank you mentors and the aevy team for giving this
                            opportunity to us to learn the skill. TYSM!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sixth_section_second_div_ka_second_content">
                    <div>
                        <h5>Rohit Tarale - Cohort 1</h5>
                        <p>I joined this cohort because I just wanted to learn something new, didnt expect it to be so great. I had never edited before on premiere. Best part for me was everything was taught from scratch, I learnt a lot and the learning skyrocketed after I joined as an intern. Trust me investing in this cohort was 1000% worth</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h5>Neeraj - Cohort 1</h5>
                        <p>Hey bro, first of all i would like to thanks you for this cohort, if you wouldn't have called me, to main cohort main part nhi leta but u told me the benefits and all and so i decided to take part. And now yesterday i got hired by a agency, which works with like 15 big FIFA Youtube creators. 2:44 PM First two months will be internship with stipend of 15k and after performing well in intership they'll offer me a full time role with base pay of 30k and with more time and experience it will be 50k and could go upto like 70k too.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h5>Sumit - Cohort 2</h5>
                        <p>I'm glad to inform you that, I'm hired by Swarup Rao as a Full time Video Editor at High Income Tribe. Offer letter just came in. I'm going to be moving to Bangalore and be there by Next Sundav. Grateful for all the opportunities and offers you helped me with. Because of which I was able to choose the best. A big big thanks to you, mentors & Especially all Fellow community members from cohort who helped in everything to be the best version of myself. Grateful for Everything ✨</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h5>Harshith Burjurkar - Cohort 2</h5>
                        <p>This cohort was the YouTube industry break-in for me, it not only turned me into a professional editor but also
                            taught me how content industry actually works. Before this cohort I struggled with editing as the tutorials on YouTube were unstructured and the Return Of Investment I got from this cohort is at least 100x. Now I am not only good at editing, but also got to know how to
                            curate a good video, hook the audience better, mimic editing style of top YouTubers. Now I understand the power Visual storytelling which was taught by best in industry mentors Like Ocus, Martin, Varun Kuntoor.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="seventh_section">
            <div class="seventh_section_first_div">
                <div class="sixth_section_first_div_ka_content_div">
                    <h5><span class="text_gradient_color">FUTURE OF CONTENT IS VIDEO</span></h5>
                    <h1 class="font_w_s_c_t">WHY ARE WE DOING THIS?</h1>
                    <p class="text_gradient_color_white">
                        We are a group of visual storytellers who came together with one goal in mind - create the Best Videos the internet has ever seen. Children of digital age -we live and breathe YouTube and have built one of India's fastest growing infotainment Youtube channels - AevyTV.
                        <br><br><br>
                        Along the journey we realized that there are many creators like us who want to create top notch content but don’t have the right resources or mentors to guide them — The state of video education is broken.
                        <br><br><br>
                        That’s why we decided to build an ecosystem where you get access to the top video creators and editors and also get to learn the whole process of video content creation end to end. From scripting, storyboarding, shooting, editing, sound design, performance metrics, Youtube analytics — we will teach you how to think and build like the top 1% video producers in the world.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="seventh_section_second_div">
                <div class="sixth_section_first_div_ka_video_div">
                    <video src="video/2.mp4" loop controls></video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="eight_section">
            <div class="eight_section_first_div">
                <h5><span class="text_gradient_color">THE APPLICATION LAYER : TOOLS & SKILLS</span></h5>
                <div><h1 class="font_w_s_c_t">CUT THE BS SHORT! TELL ME WHAT TOOLS AM I GOING TO MASTER?</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="eight_section_second_div">
                <div class="eight_section_second_div_ka_backdiv"></div>
                <img src="images/infographic.svg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nine_section">
            <div class="nine_section_ka_first_div">
                <h5><span class="text_gradient_color">WHAT MAKES US UNIQUE</span></h5>
                <h1 class="font_w_s_c_t">YES, BUT WHY SHOULD I CHOOSE YOU?</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="nine_section_ka_second_div">
                <div class="nine_section_ka_second_div_ka_content_div">
                    <div><img src="images/Group-120-1.svg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                    <h5>Amazing Community</h5>
                    <p>Unlike all the other last-gen video editing courses out there, we give a community first learning experience. Not only do you learn, you make awesome life-long friends too.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="nine_section_ka_second_div_ka_content_div">
                    <div><img src="images/Group-125.svg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                    <h5>Never seen before Placements</h5>
                    <p>Our placement rates surpass the placements of top tier Indian institutions. You focus on becoming a top editor, and we will focus on getting you a job with the best creators and companies.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="nine_section_ka_second_div_ka_content_div">
                    <div><img src="images/Group_1.svg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                    <h5>Network of top Indian Creators</h5>
                    <p>We have a network of the top creators across the globe who are looking to hire from the next cohort. With Aevy, you get access and a chance to work with all the biggest names in the industry.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ten_section">
            <div class="ten_section_first_div">
                <img src="images/rocket.png" alt="">
                <img src="images/Union-1.svg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="ten_section_second_div">
                <h1 class="font_w_s_c_t">START YOUR JOURNEY TO BECOME A VIDEO EDITING NINJA</h1>
                <button>ENROLL NOW <img src="images/arrow-right-up.svg" alt="" srcset=""></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="footer_first_section">
                <img src="images/yuewr.png" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="footer_second_section">
                <div class="footer_second_section_contact">
                    <div class="footer_second_section_contactAll">
                            <div><img src="images/Frame-61.svg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                            <div><p>+91 97409 81289</p></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer_second_section_contactAll">
                        <div><img src="images/Frame-61-1.svg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                        <div><p>info@aevytv.com</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="footer_second_section_policy">
                    <div class="footer_second_section_contact">
                        <div class="footer_second_section_contactAll">
                            <div><img src="images/privacy1.svg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                            <p>Privacy Policy</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer_second_section_contactAll">
                            <div><img src="images/cs.svg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                            <p>Customer Supprt</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer_second_section_contactAll">
                            <div><img src="images/tos.svg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                            <p>Terms OS</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer_second_section_contactAll">
                            <div><img src="images/refund.svg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
                            <p>Refund Policy</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer_third_section">
                <p>© COPYRIGHT 2022 AEVY VENTURES PVT. LTD.</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be very useful, but I will still post it here.

Something is overflowing, and if I remember correctly overflows cause scrolling. I have found that it seems to be something about your div element with the class `first_section`, It's likely the cause is the H1 element within.

Hope this helps a little.

EDIT: It seems that most of the sections overflow.